# bash script fail when a command wait ffmpeg to finish

Tags: python, node.js, bash, ffmpeg, avconv

In ubuntu 13.04 have a node.js server that launch for certain events, a script like this:

```
#! /bin/bash
...
...

avconv -i "$dir$video" -ss "$ss.000" -t $tt -threads 0 "$folder/$dif.webm"

y_uid=$(/app/youtube-uploader "$folder/$dif.webm" "$label" "$desc" | grep 'watch' | sed 's/v=/ /g' | awk '{print$2}')

echo "$y_uid" >> ~/log/yt.log
...
...
```

if avconv (ffmpeg) process a small file (less then 30 minutes of encoding), the script works fine, but if avconv runs for hours, the next command "...youtube-uploader..." (that is a python based application) doesn't work (but if i try to launch it manually, it will go fine).

I have also tried to launch the next command inside a loop that check if the variable "$y_uid" is empty, so it will try to repeat youtube-uploader until it find a right value, but it will continue to stay in background and will try forever.. (and it is strange, because if i try to launch the command manually, it works fine..).

Summarizing, seems like that if avconv run for hours, the avconv process will generate a file that is not recognised or locked or a ghost file for the same script (but is recognised if the command is launched outside the script), if it is a small encoding, it will work fine.

Unfortunatelly It is difficult to debug or test, because i have every time to wait for hours, please help!

**UPDATE**

I think the problem is related at the buffer size of node.js OR some other buffer that store the standard output of ffmpeg. Just correct

```
avconv -i "$dir$video" -ss "$ss.000" -t $tt -threads 0 "$folder/$dif.webm"
```

in

```
avconv -i "$dir$video" -ss "$ss.000" -t $tt -threads 0 "$folder/$dif.webm" &> /dev/null
```

so all the ffmpeg output not full the buffer memory and everythings go well

Comment: 1. What happens if  you process that big file outside of the script, does it finally finish? 2. Please indicate what OS you are using. If this is happening inside of cygwin on windows, then your theory about non-recognized files etc is very possible. Good luck!

Comment: 1 as i write, outside the script every commands works fine, and if the script is terminated (and fail to elaborate the commands after ffmpeg), i can ever continue to launch manually the other commands with success.
2 the os is ubuntu and the script is launched by a nodejs server (now i have updated with that information)

Comment: Any chance the nodejs server gets impatient with a script that runs too long, i.e. applies a timeout and just drops it?

Comment: down in the script there are other commands and works well. The part that seems don't works, is the post processing of the file generated inside the script, but the script stay alive and do all the other stuffs that not take care about the file encoded